# How to ignore some parameters in TQuery

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2000, delphi-5, bde, tquery

If i have a SQL statement like below

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CID = :vCID AND DataType = :vDataType
```

And usually i use TQuery to get some data like below

```
aQuery.ParamByName('vCID').Value := '0025';
aQuery.ParamByName('vDataType').AsInteger := 1;
```

But how can i ignore the "CID" key to get a SQL like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DataType = :vDataType
```

I've try the below synctax, but failed

```
aQuery.ParamByName('vCID').Value := '%';
aQuery.ParamByName('vDataType').AsInteger := 1;
```

Please help me out, thank you.

Comment: @Arioch'The, i'm using Delphi5 & SQL Server 2000

Comment: that should be in the question tags or at least in body, not burried in comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option is to simply use separate queries:

```
aQueryBoth.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CID = :vCID AND DataType = :vDataType';
...
aQueryBoth.ParamByName('vCID').Value := '0025';
aQueryBoth.ParamByName('vDataType').AsInteger := 1;
```

```
aQueryDataType.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DataType = :vDataType';
...
aQueryDataType.ParamByName('vDataType').AsInteger := 1;
```

Answer (score 8):

Change your Query to

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE CID = ISNULL(:vCID,CID) AND DataType = ISNULL(:vDataType,DataType)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE COALESCE(CID,'') = COALESCE(:vCID,CID,'') 
  AND COALESCE(DataType,0) = COALESCE(:vDataType,DataType,0)
```

The second one would handle the case of NULL values in the table too.

The Parameter you don't want to use can be set to `Unassigned`

```
aQuery.ParamByName('vCID').Value := Unassigned; // <<
aQuery.ParamByName('vDataType').AsInteger := 1;
```

Since :vCid is NULL it will be evaluated as `CID = CID`

Comment: that should fail if CID field is actually NULL

Comment: @Arioch'The thank you for the hint, I did an edit regarding this case.

Comment: "The second one would handle the case of NULL values" - but at the price of disabling of indexed search over CID - only natural scan

Answer (score 2):

Usual but somewhat verbose way is to introduce yet another parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
   WHERE ( ( CID = :vCID ) OR ( :IgnoreCID <> 0 )) 
     AND ( DataType = :vDataType )
```

Then turning your queries into

```
aQuery.ParamByName('vCID').Value := '0025';
aQuery.ParamByName('IgnoreCID').AsInteger := 0;
aQuery.ParamByName('vDataType').AsInteger := 1;
```

or

```
aQuery.ParamByName('vCID').Value := Unassigned;
aQuery.ParamByName('IgnoreCID').AsInteger := 1;
aQuery.ParamByName('vDataType').AsInteger := 1;
```

If the server has decent SQL Optimizer, then it would figure out when the 1st parameter is worth checking or not.